# Still compare committed difference after squash merging

Tags: git, github, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-squash

I have merged a `develop` branch into `main` branch using `squash merge`. Let's say there are commit A, B, C merged into `main` from `develop`. The changes are successfully merged. I can see the squash commit on the `main` branch and the files are updated.

After that, I created a new branch (`b-new`) from `develop` and merged it into `develop`. However, When I try to sync `main` with `develop` again, I can still see the old differences (commit A, B, C). How to resolve this issue?

To clean up:

- PR #1: merge commit A, B, C from `develop` into `main`
- PR #2: merge `b-new` into `develop`
- PR #3: merge `develop` into `main` again (where I see old difference and am stuck right now)
- I am not able to directly push changes to main without 1 approval
- The changes will not affect others, so don't need to worry about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This scenario, where you have two long-running branches and are using squash merges, is [described in the Git FAQ in some detail](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#long-running-squash-merge).  Roughly, the answer is that you are bound for a world of pain if you use squash merges with two long-lived branches and there's no way to avoid it.

If `develop` is intended to be a feature branch, then to avoid seeing those commits, you should recreate it off of `main` each time, either by deleting it first, or by using `git checkout -B develop main`.  If `develop` is intended to be a long-running branch along with `main`, then you need to not use squash merges.