# Keeping commit history in develop branch but only merge commits in master branch

Tags: git, merge

I would like to keep the history of commits in develop but only the merge commits in main. I thought squash merges would do that, but evidently it creates the problem described here: [after squash merge, the commit history still shows up in merge requests as differences between the branches, even though they should be identical at that point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261204/still-compare-committed-difference-after-squash-merging).

Is there another way to accomplish this? Maybe I don't need to keep the commits in develop, but I would like to be able to browse back through them on our company bitbucket account.

Comment: You could squash the commits before merging them into main. That way they'd be squashed in both branches. Similarly, you could rebase develop on main (which is best practice anyway) after merging a sqashed set of commits. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a misunderstanding of what a merge is, what a branch is, and what Git is.

Just to sum up quickly:

- Git is an acyclic directed graph consisting of commits, each commit (except the first one ever created) having at least one parent. The "history" is generated simply by following the *parent chain* backwards from any given commit.
- A branch is merely a name for one commit.
- A merge commit, unlike normal commits that you make by the edit-add-commit cycle, is created entirely by Git itself. It has, by definition, at least *two* parents; typically (though not necessarily), before the merge, these were the branch you were "in" when you said `git merge` and the branch that was the "direct object" of that command, `git merge <otherbranch>`.

Now then. You are absolutely right to want "to be able to browse back through" the commits merged into main, i.e. to maintain a *true history* expressed in the topology of the repo. Only a merge commit can do that.

Given that desire, and given the assumption that this is what you want to do, it is meaningless and useless to say "keep the history of commits in develop but only the merge commits". By definition of a branch, only one commit is `main`. The other commits that you are wrongly thinking of being "in main" are the sum total of all commits *reachable by way of the parent chains from the main commit and any parent of any of those commits*. That is what history *is*, as I stipulated at the outset.

(To put it another way - more startlingly, perhaps, and therefore possibly more helpfully - *every branch "contains" the entire history all the way back to the first commit ever made in this repo.*)

Therefore it is impossible to have a true merge commit "in main" (or any branch) without also having all the commits that were in the history of *either* of the two branches that were merged at the time that merge commit was created.

So don't worry, be happy. You can always *walk* the history while simply *ignoring* second parents of all merges, in which case you will get the single chain of merge commits that you are looking for, by saying e.g.

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --first-parent
```

That command will give you the view of main that you are looking for. But that is not because that is what main *is* but because it is how *you* elect to *view* the history.

Comment: For more about what merges are, including a helpful discussion of why repeatedly squash merging from one long-lived branch to another long-lived branch is certain to be a merge conflict nightmare, see my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am thinking about this.